# Send hex data to Ethernet or LAN using Visual Basic 6.0

Tags: vb6

I wanted to send hex data to Ethernet or LAN using [Visual Basic 6.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic#Timeline). The hex data will be like:

> AB7745683ACB76B34E5FF5E99EBC5F878A6BC8E9DF9876BCEA89

On the form I have a text box in which the user will input this data.

How can I send this hex data to LAN or Ethernet using Visual Basic 6.0?

Comment: So you want to send an array of bytes to something listening on an IP address? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa228119(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: Is this question about VBA or VB6?  They are not the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'1 form with:
'    1 textbox control: name=Text1
'    1 winsock control: name=Winsock1
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
  SendCmd Text1.Text
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
  Text1.Text = "AB7745683ACB76B34E5FF5E99EBC5F878A6BC8E9DF9876BCEA89"
End Sub

Private Sub SendCmd(strHex As String)
  Dim strCmd As String
  With Winsock1
    'make sure we are connected
    DoConnect
    'convert hex to cmd
    strCmd = Hex2Cmd(strHex)
    'send cmd
    .SendData strCmd
  End With 'Winsock1
End Sub

Private Sub DoConnect()
  With Winsock1
    If .State <> sckConnected Then
      .Connect "192.168.98.17", 5001 'Destination IP address and port
      Do Until .State = sckConnected
        DoEvents
      Loop
    End If
  End With 'Winsock1
End Sub

Private Function Hex2Cmd(strHex As String) As String
  Dim intHex As Integer
  Dim strCmd As String
  strCmd = ""
  For intHex = 1 To Len(strHex) Step 2
    strCmd = strCmd & Chr$(Val("&H" & Mid$(strHex, intHex, 2)))
  Next intHex
  Hex2Cmd = strCmd
End Function
```